# Why is my script language parser not working?

Tags: java, command-line

I am making a parser for a language I call "Dint" in Java, and I added a statement for debugging: `System.out.println("tok's val: "+tok);` and it has the same value as the parser, but won't print "Found a print", why?

I have tried moving statements between lines, I have tried to look up the issue, and as a last resort I added that debugging statement, but I am confused as to why it won't work.

```java
public class Dint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome Dint ISE v0.0.1! use \"help\" for help!\n");
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String In = Input.nextLine();
        boolean Program = true;
        while(Program) {
            String tok = "";
            String string = "";
            int state = 0;
            String[] strings = new String[100];
            for(int i = 0; i < In.length();) {
                tok += In.charAt(i);
                if(tok == " ") {
                    tok = "";
                } else if(tok == "\"") {
                    tok = "";
                } else if(tok == "out") {
                    System.out.println("Found a print");
                    tok = "";
                }
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println("tok's value: "+tok);
            In = Input.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I get

```
out
tok's val: out
```

When I expected to get:

```
out
Found a print
tok's val: out
```

Comment: once you fix the tests, how do you expect to get `tok's val: out` if you set `tok = "";` for every positive test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `tok == " "` you should use `tok.equals(" ")`

Answer (score 0):

Strings should be compared using `.equals(String)` and not using `==`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `equals` instead of `==`.In comon case better to use expression like `" ".equals(yourVariable)` to avoid NPE.